Convert bash array to JSON and write to file
I have a bash array that I want to convert to json and write to file. Suppose it is
my_strings=("hello" "world")

I have managed to convert it to json and write to file with:
for f in "${my_strings[@]}"; do printf '%s' "$f" | jq -R -s .; done | jq -s >> test_.json

and the output resulting file looks like:
[
  "hello",
  "world"
]

However, the output I would like to have is
{
    "strings_":
    [
        "hello",
        "world"
    ]
 }

I've tried prepend and append the graphs and the key like this:
printf '{\n\t"strings_":\n' > test_.json; for f in "${my_strings[@]}"; do printf '%s' "$f" | jq -R -s .; done | jq -s >> test_.json; printf "}\n" >> test_.json

but the resulting indentation is not good.
Is there a better way to do this?

in simple
echo '{"strings":'$(cat test_.json)'}' | jq
#
{
  "strings": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ]
}


@Popeye in your command you are hard coding the strings of the array, in general these are from a bash array

Uh, no, they're not. The comment contains the result but that's not actually part of the code.

Then I don't understand your comment: it seems to me that you are reading a file with cat to create the json. I need to create the json and then write to file

You're looking for something like this:
$ my_strings=("hello" "world")
$ jq -n --args '{strings_: $ARGS.positional}' "${my_strings[@]}"
{
  "strings_": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ]
}

